# How to remove duplicate entries for Python env interpreter in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, development-environment

I'm using Windows 10 and I'm not sure why I have such a long list of the same Python env when I select the interpreter for my Jupyter notebook. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Currently have no lead in how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the page by clicking the Refresh button in the top right corner of the panel.

[image]

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling the **Python** extension or uninstalling vscode and reinstalling it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried resinstalling Python extension and vscode, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try uninstalling completely and reinstalling. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall